# Raspberry Pi, JCblock and Trendnet TFM 561U. Dosen't seem to work

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

The dev suggested to ask here to get more help.
This is what is happening, I bought a Raspberry Pi (second one, I know how to handle them, and I'm used to apt and ssh) and a Trendnet TFM561U modem, downloaded NOOBS, did the initial setup with an extra in the shape of Webmin. So far aside from Webmin, it's a vanilla Raspbian. I then downloaded JCblock ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcblock/ ) and following the instructions here http://weeklytechforum.com/2013/03/28/block-unwanted-calls-with-a-raspberry-pi/ I edited the files that needed editing and finally compiled. I found out what serial port the modem was using (same as the guide! cool) and finally proceeded to test it. That's where the trouble started.
The differences between me and the guide is that I'm in Italy, so the dev of JCblock made me edit the source with a few extra lines of code to talk to the modem... now it's a great time to point out that while I can edit code and recompile it, this is C and I absolutly have no clue about it, knowing just some basics from Pascal and a bit of Visual Basic, so in the end I'm editing the source blindly, just guessing where things need to go. Anyway the edits are to send the  Country Code command: AT+GCI=59\r and Caller ID command: AT+VCID=1\r but we do not seem to be geting caller ID data from the modem.

What I'm expecting to see: I call with my cellphone (and that number is in the blacklist) the Raspberry doesn't make the phone ring, or in case of wrong configuration of the blacklist I get some output that will show a call not filtered.

What I get: the phone rings, the modem data light flashes, the program dosen't output anything.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
So, I went ahead and used NCID to see what would happen.
As it generates a cornucopia of data, I think it can be useful

```html
Started: 10/27/2014 22:24:54
Server: ncidd (NCID) 1.0
API: 1.0 Feature Set 1 2 3 4
Command line: ncidd
              -Dv3
Logfile: /var/log/ncidd.log
Processed config file: /etc/ncid/ncidd.conf
Verbose level: 3
Configured to send 'cidlog' to clients.
Configured to send 'cidinfo' to clients.
Helper tools:
    /usr/bin/cidupdate
    /usr/bin/ncidutil
Processed alias file: /etc/ncid/ncidd.alias
Alias Table:
    Number of Entries: 1
Leading 1 from a call required in an alias definition
Calls in the blacklist file will be terminated
Processed blacklist file: /etc/ncid/ncidd.blacklist
Blacklist Table:
    Number of Entries: 12
Calls in the whitelist file will not be terminated
Processed whitelist file: /etc/ncid/ncidd.whitelist
Whitelist Table:
    Number of Entries: 0
CID logfile: /var/log/cidcall.log
CID logfile maximum size: 110000 bytes
Data logfile not present: /var/log/ciddata.log
Maximum number of clients/gateways: 25
Telephone Line Identifier: -
TTY port opened: /dev/ttyACM0
TTY port speed: 19200
TTY lock file: /var/lock/LCK..ttyACM0
TTY port control signals enabled
CallerID from AT Modem and optional gateways
Handles modem calls without Caller ID
Sent Modem 20 of 20 characters: 
AT Z S0=0 E1 V1 Q0
Modem response: 26 characters in 1 read:
AT Z S0=0 E1 V1 Q0
OK

Try 1 to init modem: return = 0.
Modem initialized.
Sent Modem 6 of 6 characters: 
ATI3
Modem response: 39 characters in 1 read:
ATI3
CX93001-EIS_V0.2002-V92

OK

Sent Modem 9 of 9 characters: 
AT+GCI?
Modem response: 27 characters in 1 read:
AT+GCI?
+GCI: 59

OK

Sent Modem 13 of 13 characters: 
AT+FCLASS=?
Modem response: 32 characters in 1 read:
AT+FCLASS=?
0,1,1.0,8

OK

Sent Modem 11 of 11 characters: 
AT+VCID=1
Modem response: 17 characters in 1 read:
AT+VCID=1
OK

Modem set for CallerID.
Hangup option set to hangup on a blacklisted call
Modem used for CID and to terminate calls
Network Port: 3333
Debug Mode
Not using PID file, there was no '-P' option.
Modem is fd 4
NCID connection socket is sd 5 pos 1


RING
CIDINFO: *LINE*POTS*RING*1*TIME*22:25:21*

CIDINFO: *LINE*POTS*RING*0*TIME*22:25:33*
```

What I can tell from this, is that it should be properly set up to hang up for a blacklisted number (my cellphone, for testing purposes) and that no caller id gets to the software. About that, it's important to point out how we have a mess of different phones (make, model, cordless, wired...) at home, and all of them do show 1 missed call from me. So at least I can confirm that the caller id is being sent.

Answer (score 3):

I looked on [Trendnet TFM561U description page](http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=130_TFM-561U) and Amazon for this modem and didn't see "caller ID" in the description. 
Your modem looks like it has Caller ID because its response to the activate caller ID command is "OK":

`AT+VCID=1
OK`

But looking at
[Testing Modem Caller ID Support with HyperTerminal (or Putty) page](http://ascendis.com/callerid/help/hyperterminal_test.php)

> However, if, in step 8), the modem responded with "OK", then you probably have the correct string.  In this case, either your phone line does not have caller id enabled (this can be tested with a hardware caller id device), or the modem does not support caller id.  **The latter is possible even if, in step 8), the modem responded with "OK", since many modems use the same firmware regardless of whether the modem contains the appropriate caller id hardware.  In other words, many modems don't know whether they have caller id support!**

I would say return your modem and get one that has "caller ID" in the description.

Comment: This is interesting. The weird part is that I used the same modem that was mentioned in the guide (so, at least in theory, with CID support) and looking around it seems that at least another person used it for this. While picking a different modem would possibly fix it, an important thing would be full linux compatibility. BUT! You got me some interesting, very interesting info... namely how to test it on Windows. That's surely worth a try, so thanks :D would upvote, but I need more reputation, it seems.

Comment: AHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA! So, your help has been way more than I'd imagine. I tried the steps in the link you so SO helpfully offered and it didn't work, giving the usual, lame "RING". Then I typed AT+VCID=1 in the modem settings in Windows, connected again via Putty, called and BAM! date, time and number. Now I only need to find out how to do that in Linux.

Comment: You can use putty on the pi to play around with and I did play around with it 
and then I found that my modem has auto answer on by default and so I added ATS0=0 to the init_modem function to turn it off.

Comment: @Alessandro you should mark the answer as the right answer then.